# OpenCV: How to calculate max(R,G,B)

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Sadly the OpenCV documentation has been written for mathematicians only or for those who already know how to use OpenCV.

I want to do such a simple thing as getting the highest value of R,G,B for each pixel and write it to a new gray scale image. I tried `merge()`, `split()` and others but without success.

The following function does exactly what I want, but I wonder if OpenCV could do that simpler.

```
Mat CalcRGBmax(Mat i_RGB)
{
    if (i_RGB.channels() != 3)
        throw "24 bit color image expected.";

    Mat i_Gray(i_RGB.rows, i_RGB.cols, CV_8UC1);

    for (int Y=0; Y<i_RGB.rows; Y++)
    {
        BYTE* pu8_Src = i_RGB. ptr<BYTE>(Y);
        BYTE* pu8_Dst = i_Gray.ptr<BYTE>(Y);

        int P = 0;
        for (int X=0; X<i_RGB.cols; X++)
        {         
            BYTE B = pu8_Src[P++];
            BYTE G = pu8_Src[P++];
            BYTE R = pu8_Src[P++];

            pu8_Dst[X] = max(R, max(G,B));
        }
    }
    return i_Gray;
}
```

Comment: Your code actually seems pretty straightforward to me. I don't know OpenCV well enough to answer, though.

Comment: Incidentally, what do you need this for? Wouldn't it be better to convert the image to HSL and use L as the graylevel?

Comment: Calculating HSL to get a grayscale image is too complicated. This could easier be done with cvtColor(..., CV_RGB2GRAY). But this is not what I want. The gray value is calculated based on the sensibility of the humany eye: Gray = 59% Green + 30% Red + 11% Blue. What I want is max(R,G,B)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code will be much faster than this, but this is how to do it with [split()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) and [max()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#max):

```
Mat CalcRGBmax(Mat i_RGB)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> planes(3);
    cv::split(i_RGB, planes);
    return cv::Mat(cv::max(planes[2], cv::max(planes[1], planes[0])));
}
```

Comment: Great! That was the answer I expected. I measured the speed and was very surprised. On my AMD Sempron 2300 I call the both functions (mine and yours) 300 times. The result is: My code= 9 seconds. Your code= 10 seconds!
It seems that the OpenCV guys did everything in their power to optimize for speed. The speed of OpenCV is extremely good.