# Optimising getting OR of Mat Channels

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to to convert a BGR cv::Mat to gray using this formula `Gray=B OR G OR R; pixel-wise operation`. I tried this:

```
cv::Mat diff_channels[3];
cv::split(diff, diff_channels);
diff = diff_channels[0] | diff_channels[1] | diff_channels[2];
```

Can this be achieved with better approach?

Also, if I want to achieve `Gray=MAX(B,G,R); pixel-wise operation` any suggestion ?

Comment: What's the declaration of `diff`?

Comment: For the max, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/24688707/2589776.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't contain any suitable built-in function to process separate channels in such way. If you want to get maximum performance you may implement this procedure by yourself. I suggest you something like this:

```
void calcOrChannels(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
  CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);
  int rows = src.rows, cols = src.cols;

  dst.create(src.size(), CV_8UC1);

  if (src.isContinuous() && dst.isContinuous())
  {
    cols = rows * cols;
    rows = 1;
  }

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
  {
    const uchar* src_ptr = src.ptr<uchar>(row);
    uchar* dst_ptr = dst.ptr<uchar>(row);

    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
      dst_ptr[col] = src_ptr[0] | src_ptr[1] | src_ptr[2]; // std::max(src_ptr[0], std::max(src_ptr[1], src_ptr[2]))
      src_ptr += 3;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that you need to test performance of this function on your hardware, since it loses benefits by using SIMD instruction and parallelism which implemented (or maybe implemeted later) in OpenCV. 
But this procedure use less additional memory and arithmetical operations. I guess that it would work faster on the most systems (especially embedded). It also depends on sizes of your matrices.

Timings on my system (Core i7-4790):

```
| Matrix size | OpenCV (ms) | My (ms) |
|:-----------:|------------:|---------|
| 1280*720    | 4           | 1       |
| 1920*1080   | 8           | 2       |
| 4096*3112   | 41          | 17      |
```

Comment: Thanks , but in this case, Will not I loose the optimization of OpenCV like paralleling the process?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Great question! I updated answer. Also you can accelerate this function using parallel backend from OpenCV (`cv::parallel_for`). If you have problem with it, let me now and I will help you.

Comment: @akarsakov I just posted an answer with `parallel_for_`. In general your approach is better.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cv::ParallelLoopBody` with `cv::parallel_for_` to use OpenCV Concurrency API:

```
class ParallelBGRtoGrayOR : public ParallelLoopBody
{
    const Mat3b src;
    mutable Mat1b dst;

public:
    ParallelBGRtoGrayOR(const Mat3b& _src, Mat1b& _dst) : ParallelLoopBody(), src(_src), dst(_dst) {}

    virtual void operator()(const Range& range) const
    {
        int rows = range.end - range.start;
        int cols = src.cols;
        int len = rows * cols;

        const uchar* yS = src.ptr<uchar>(range.start);
        uchar* yD = dst.ptr<uchar>(range.start);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i, yD++, yS += 3)
        {
            *yD = yS[0] | yS[1] | yS[2];
            //*yD = std::max(yS[0], std::max(yS[1], yS[2]));
        }
    }
};

void cvtBgrToGray_OR_Miki(const Mat3b& src, Mat1b& dst)
{
    dst.create(src.rows, src.cols);
    parallel_for_(Range(0, src.rows), ParallelBGRtoGrayOR(src, dst), -1);
}
```

**Test**

Testing with your and @akarsakov method, I got (time in ms):

```
Size:           akarsakov       Humam Helfawi   Miki            OpenCV (not same operation)

[10 x 10]       0.00109963      0.0711094       2.60722         0.0934685
[100 x 100]     0.0106298       0.0373874       0.0461844       0.0395867
[1000 x 1000]   1.1799          3.30622         0.747382        1.61646
[1280 x 720]    1.07324         2.91585         0.520858        0.9893
[1920 x 1080]   2.31252         6.87818         1.11502         1.94011
[4096 x 3112]   14.3454         42.0125         6.79644         12.0754
[10000 x 10000] 115.575         321.145         61.1544         93.8846
```

**Considerations**

@akarsakov method (working smartly on raw data) is in general the better approach, since it's very fast and easier to write. Using the `ParallelLoopBody` has some advantage only with large images (at least on my pc).

I assumed source image to be continuous. This check should be done in practice.

**Testing code**

You can evaluate the results on your pc using this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class ParallelBGRtoGrayOR : public ParallelLoopBody
{
    const Mat3b src;
    mutable Mat1b dst;

public:
    ParallelBGRtoGrayOR(const Mat3b& _src, Mat1b& _dst) : ParallelLoopBody(), src(_src), dst(_dst) {}

    virtual void operator()(const Range& range) const
    {
        int rows = range.end - range.start;
        int cols = src.cols;
        int len = rows * cols;

        const uchar* yS = src.ptr<uchar>(range.start);
        uchar* yD = dst.ptr<uchar>(range.start);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i, yD++, yS += 3)
        {
            *yD = yS[0] | yS[1] | yS[2];
            //*yD = std::max(yS[0], std::max(yS[1], yS[2]));
        }
    }
};

void cvtBgrToGray_OR_Miki(const Mat3b& src, Mat1b& dst)
{
    dst.create(src.rows, src.cols);
    parallel_for_(Range(0, src.rows), ParallelBGRtoGrayOR(src, dst), -1);
}


// credits to @akarsakov
void cvtBgrToGray_OR_akarsakov(const Mat3b& src, Mat1b& dst)
{
    int rows = src.rows, cols = src.cols;
    dst.create(src.size());
    if (src.isContinuous() && dst.isContinuous())
    {
        cols = rows * cols;
        rows = 1;
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        const uchar* src_ptr = src.ptr<uchar>(row);
        uchar* dst_ptr = dst.ptr<uchar>(row);

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            dst_ptr[col] = src_ptr[0] | src_ptr[1] | src_ptr[2];
            //dst_ptr[col] = std::max(src_ptr[0], std::max(src_ptr[1], src_ptr[2]));
            src_ptr += 3;
        }
    }
}

// credits to @Humam_Helfawi
void cvtBgrToGray_OR_Humam_Helfawi(const Mat3b& src, Mat1b& dst)
{
    cv::Mat channels[3];
    cv::split(src, channels);
    dst = channels[0] | channels[1] | channels[2];
}



int main()
{
    vector<Size> sizes{ Size(10, 10), Size(100, 100), Size(1000, 1000), Size(1280, 720), Size(1920, 1080), Size(4096, 3112), Size(10000, 10000) };

    cout << "Size: \t\takarsakov \tHumam Helfawi \tMiki \tOpenCV (not same operation)" << endl;

    for (int is = 0; is < sizes.size(); ++is)
    {
        Size sz = sizes[is];

        cout << sz << "\t";

        Mat3b img(sz);
        randu(img, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        Mat1b gray_akarsakov;
        Mat1b gray_Miki;
        Mat1b gray_Humam;
        Mat1b grayOpenCV;


        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        cvtBgrToGray_OR_akarsakov(img, gray_akarsakov);

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << toc << " \t";



        tic = double(getTickCount());

        cvtBgrToGray_OR_Humam_Helfawi(img, gray_Humam);

        toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << toc << " \t";



        tic = double(getTickCount());

        cvtBgrToGray_OR_Miki(img, gray_Miki);

        toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << toc << " \t";


        tic = double(getTickCount());

        cvtColor(img, grayOpenCV, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << toc << endl;

    }


    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! first time see my name in other people's code :D
Great Answer and efforts,, really thank you

Comment: Great work! Thanks for your effort! Just one little remark: `int len = rows * cols;` will work only for continuous matrices (not for submats), but it is rarely case.

Comment: Sure, I remarked that in the considerations @akarsakov

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to share my results

```
Size:           akarsakov       Humam Helfawi   Miki    OpenCV (not same operation)
[10 x 10]       0.00733416      1.03216         1.15244         0.044005
[100 x 100]     0.078231        0.0816536       0.185799        0.043516
[1000 x 1000]   7.81039         5.89764         40.7481         3.49253
[1280 x 720]    7.61432         5.31824         8.74916         1.70397
[1920 x 1080]   16.0256         12.8186         9.32367         3.6045
[4096 x 3112]   97.7365         72.6287         49.3452         22.9545
[10000 x 10000] 763.509         575.718         402.729         197.01
```

EDIT: i have a new laptop and tested the code again on it and on the older one. it seems the difference of results depend on different built configurations of OpenCV

1.Intel(R)_Core(TM)_i5-3230M_CPU_@_2.60GHz

```
Size:           akarsakov       Humam Helfawi   Miki    OpenCV (not same operation)
[10 x 10]       0.00276318      0.0627636       0.445661        0.0351318
[100 x 100]     0.0303949       0.0734216       0.0457898       0.0663162
[1000 x 1000]   3.01186         5.30727         2.11699         3.05805
[1280 x 720]    2.59975         4.91806         1.82014         2.69528
[1920 x 1080]   5.97478         11.5406         3.56213         5.52556
[4096 x 3112]   37.3076         64.1728         22.4575         35.0398
[10000 x 10000] 284.249         510.332         175.626         268.652
```

2.Intel(R)_Core(TM)2_Duo_CPU_____T6500__@_2.10GHz

```
Size:           akarsakov       Humam Helfawi   Miki    OpenCV (not same operation)
[10 x 10]       0.00586751      0.107571        24.1966         1.50844
[100 x 100]     0.0704101       0.154511        0.308044        0.119306
[1000 x 1000]   7.00825         11.072          3.44912         5.25778
[1280 x 720]    6.63322         9.88529         3.91999         5.0177
[1920 x 1080]   14.6199         21.8047         7.19357         10.9551
[4096 x 3112]   85.8226         133.165         42.4392         64.2184
[10000 x 10000] 675.604         1050.19         334.334         507.87
```