# Luminosity theshold grayscaling in OpenCV for custom values

Tags: c++, opencv

To convert image to Grayscale for luminous value `Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B`, there is a direct function -

```
cvtColor(img, img, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

I want to have custom value -

```
Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B;
```

Comment: You can create new image and set all the pixel values in a loop considering your input image pixel's R,G,B values and your custom conversion formula.

Comment: you can use the code from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34315148/5294258) and change only `*yD = yS[0] | yS[1] | yS[2];` to `*yD = ( 0.0722 * yS[0] ) + ( 0.7152 * yS[1] ) + (  0.2126 * yS[2] );` ( be aware of BGR order ). than thank @Miki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimising getting OR of Mat Channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308932/optimising-getting-or-of-mat-channels)

Comment: [akarsakov solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311841/5008845) is also a good one. Thanks @sturkmen ;D